# Open GL ES 2.0 draw a square

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to follow the Android Developers "Displaying graphics with OpenGL ES" tutorial.
In the first part, I had to draw a triangle and it has been ok. Now I should draw a square, by using a Square class that can be defined by following the tutorial.
When I try to draw (using a draw() method that I mostly copied from the Triangle class), the screen shows only a triangle that's half of the defined square (obviously I've commented out the triangle.draw() line...).

Here's my code, has someone any hint to resolve it?

Square.java:

```
public class Square {

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;

    private final int mProgram;

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_Position = vPosition;" +
                    "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
                    "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                    "}";

    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    static float squareCoords[] = {
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
            0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right

    // Set color with red, green, blue and alpha (opacity) values
    float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };

    private short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices

    public Square() {
        // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareCoords.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(drawOrder.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);

        int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                fragmentShaderCode);

        // create empty OpenGL ES Program
        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);

        // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);

        // creates OpenGL ES program executables
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
    }

    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mColorHandle;

    private final int vertexCount = squareCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

    public void draw() {
        // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

        // Set color for drawing the triangle
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

        // Draw the square
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Triangle primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives)

You have 4 vertex coordinates, which have the following arrangement:

```
static float squareCoords[] = {
   -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
   -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
    0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right
```

```
0       3
 x     x
 |     |
 |     |
 x-----x 
1       2
```

This pattern matches the primitive type `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`, but not the primitive type `GL_TRIANGLES`.

Change the primitive type to solve your issue:

```
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertexCount);
```

---

Note for the primitive type `GL_TRIANGLES` you would need 6 vertex coordinates, e.g. with the following arrangement:

```
0  3      5
 x x-----x
 | \ \   |
 |   \ \ |
 x-----x x 
1      2  4
```

The primitive type `GL_TRIANGLES` matches your index buffer:

```
private short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };
```

If you want to draw the primitives from an index  list, then you have to use [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml):

```
GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
```

Comment: Thanks, I could solve the problem by using: glDrawElements